# TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

There are many questions on this exact error. Nevertheless, I cannot find one that fixes my problem. I'm probably missing something simple but I don't know what.

In my project I just created the first ts file - initialize.ts:

```
import angular from "angular";

namespace AngularTypeScriptStarterKit {
    angular
        .module('app', []);

}
```

Now the problem is that 'angular' is marked with red, saying:

> TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular'

I have the declarations file for angular located at /typings/globals/angular/index.d.ts

Any help will be profoundly appreciated.

typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160725073351",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20170310222111"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.6.0+20170321201455"
  }
}
```

Please let me know for any other required information and I'll update my question.

Comment: any reason not switched to @types? typings is deprecated

Comment: @suraj I just switched to types and it solved my problem. Please rewrite this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: glad it worked :) .. added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typings is deprecated.

You need to use [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/angular).

Just do :

```
npm install --save-dev @types/angular
```

index.d.ts [reference](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts)

Answer (score 3):

If your application is not able to find module you should provide the typescript reference path on the first line of the file itself. Include following line of code : 
///
reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" /, 
at top of Initialize.ts In typescript reference path is required for third party libraries so that typescript compiler can understand the method definitions. More on reference path in following link : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html